# help with sql query with parentheses

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

i have following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE thread = $thread
AND (user != $user1 OR user != $user2)
```

i want the code to pick all rows that contains $thread BUT the user isn't $user1 or $user2.

is my code correct? or should it be like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE thread = $thread
(AND user != $user1 OR user != $user2)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE thread = $thread
(AND user != $user1 AND user != $user2)
```

Because you don't want if the user is either of user1 or user2, for this reason using 'AND' will be proper option here.

Also if the `$thread` is not an integer field, you need enclose it in quotes eg:

```
WHERE thread = '$thread'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM TABLE t
 WHERE t.thread = mysql_real_escape_string($thread)
   AND t.user NOT IN (mysql_real_escape_string($user1), mysql_real_escape_string($user2))
```

Please [use mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), or risk [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Mind that you don't need single quotes, because of using `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: `mysql_escape_string` is deprecated, but an alternative for PHP prior to 5.3: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Comment: @noname: Sorry, just making sure.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT *

FROM table

WHERE thread = $thread

AND user != $user1

AND user != $user2`

Comment: Just following the OP's lead. Avoiding SQL injection is important, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE thread = '$thread'
AND user NOT IN ($user1, $user2)
```

Don't know which executes faster, but this is my preferred way because I like it's readability better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also be using <> instead of !=

So:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE thread = $thread
AND user <> $user1
AND user <> $user2
```

Comment: <> and != both are same and understood by mysql

Comment: `!=` is ANSI-92, and supported by MySQL at least 4.1+